# Odata service querying results in special characters

Tags: web8, odata

I am trying to query odata service in SDL Web 8.1.
While querying I am getting special characters as result in the browser.
Please let me know if anything going incorrect in the configuration.

Regards

Comment: Please edit your question and provide bit more detail about your issues like input and output screenshots may help to understand your issue better to help you

Comment: Hi, We have recently upgraded one of our CMS environment from SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 to SDL Web 8.1. We were using OData service for content querying in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1. After upgrade to SDL web 8.1, I am trying to query same OData service, I am getting results but the Presentation Content is not showing the actual content instead its showing special characters. Please let me know if this clarifies.

Comment: @Velmurugan, as of now I am not able to capture the screenshots as required by you, I'll try to add ASAP.

Comment: Maybe you have not configured encoding on either on odata service or webapp, could you please double check?

Comment: Hi, I am accessing the OData service in Browser and as of now not consuming in any web application. I have checked the encoding for OData web service and its UTF-8. Further can you please suggest me where else I need to check the encoding configuration values.

Comment: Please edit your question and update your current encoding config? Please ensure your deployer service also configured encoding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83564/discussion-between-user2166-and-velmurugan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was not able to find any direct fix for OData.svc itself, I tried the suggested solution provided in the SDL Web 8 documentation [SDL Web 8](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-F8B49A27-F38E-4EDF-996A-0B8BE12AF106).
I created a reverse proxy url rewrite module which directed all requests coming to Odata.svc to Content.svc microservice. This seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To enable encoding to use the **jvm.xml** in your Content Delivery services config folder something like:

```
<!--
This file can be used to send application specific JVM arguments.
-->
<VirtualMachine>
  <Options>
    <!--
    Add the Option tag to define specific JVM options.
    The Option tag can define the MaximumHeapSizeInMB (-Xmx), the InitialHeapSizeInMB (-Xms) and other JVM properties(-D).
    -->
    <!-- 
    <Option Name="-Xmx" Value="400m"/>
    <Option Name="-Xms" Value="50m"/>
    -->
    <Option Name="-Dfile.encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
  </Options>
</VirtualMachine>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions but seems no luck. Any suggestions further?